# Связать базу данных с RecyclerView в Android

Tags: android, база-данных, recyclerview

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчане! Прошу вашей помощи!
У меня есть фрагмент с RecyclerView

Код:

```
package com.starikov.tester;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class PizzaMaterialFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        RecyclerView pizzaRecycler = (RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza_material, container, false);

        int[] pizzaImages = new int[Pizza.pizzas.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pizzaImages.length; i++){
            pizzaImages[i] = Pizza.pizzas[i].getImageResourceId();
        }

        CaptionedImagesAdapter adapter = new CaptionedImagesAdapter(pizzaImages);
        pizzaRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        pizzaRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        return pizzaRecycler;
    }
}
```

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pizza_recycler"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Есть класс Pizza:

```
package com.starikov.tester;

public class Pizza {

    private int imageResourceId;

    public static final Pizza[] pizzas = {
            new Pizza(R.drawable.formul_electricheskii_zaryad_ydra_atoma),
            new Pizza(R.drawable.formul_simvol_himicheskogo_elementa),
            new Pizza(R.drawable.formul_energia_svyzi_yadra),
            new Pizza(R.drawable.formul_massovoe_chislo),
            new Pizza(R.drawable.formul_defekt_mass)
    };

    private Pizza(int imageResourceId) {
        this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
    }

    public int getImageResourceId() {
        return imageResourceId;
    }
}
```

Есть CaptionedImagesAdapter(Кастомный адаптер RecyclerView):

```
package com.starikov.tester;


import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

class CaptionedImagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private int[] imageIds;

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private CardView cardView;
        public ViewHolder(CardView v){
            super(v);
            cardView = v;
        }
    }

    public CaptionedImagesAdapter(int[] imageIds){
        this.imageIds = imageIds;
    }

    @Override
    public CaptionedImagesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        CardView cv = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(cv);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.info_image);
        Drawable drawable = cardView.getResources().getDrawable(imageIds[position]);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imageIds.length;
    }
}
```

Мне нужно переделать так чтобы RecyclerView брал данные из базы данных а не из простого списка в Pizza.java. Я перерыл гугл, но не разобрался в том что было. Прошу вашей помощи!

Вот код базы данных:

```
package com.starikov.tester;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class PizzaDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DB_NAME = "pizza";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    PizzaDatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE FORMULS ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
        insertFormul(db, R.drawable.formul_electricheskii_zaryad_ydra_atoma);
        insertFormul(db, R.drawable.formul_simvol_himicheskogo_elementa);
        insertFormul(db, R.drawable.formul_energia_svyzi_yadra);
        insertFormul(db, R.drawable.formul_massovoe_chislo);
        insertFormul(db, R.drawable.formul_defekt_mass);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    }

    private static void insertFormul(SQLiteDatabase db, int resourceId){
        ContentValues formulValues = new ContentValues();
        formulValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
        db.insert("FORMULS", null, formulValues);
    }
}
```

Прошу помочь! Приведите полный код, с объяснением, я новичок и не очень сразу все понимаю!
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Вам необходимо использовать CursorLoader - как это сделать, можно прочитать в книге `Дейтел П., Дейтел Х., Уолд Э. - Android для разработчиков (Библиотека программиста) - 2016` в главе `Address Book`, там все подробно с пояснениями изложено.

Answer (score 1):

Измените ваш класс:

```
public class Pizza {

private int imageResourceId;

private Pizza(int imageResourceId) {
    this.imageResourceId = imageResourceId;
}

public int getImageResourceId() {
    return imageResourceId;
}
```

Затем в классе `PizzaDatabaseHelper` реализуйте метод получения данных с БД:

Пропишите имя таблицы БД, и получаемые данные:

```
private static final String mTableName = "FORMULS";
private static final int mImgId = "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID";
```

После метода `insertFormul` добавьте код который получит списком данных и передаст их куда вы укажите:

```
List<Pizza > getItem(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = db.query(mTableName, // a. table
            mImgId,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null);

    List<Pizza> headsItem = new ArrayList<>();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            headsItem.add(new Pizza(
                    cursor.getInteger(cursor.getColumnIndex(mImgId))));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    return headsItem;
}
```

И далее в методе `onCreate` вашего фрагмента:

```
RecyclerView pizzaRecycler = 
(RecyclerView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pizza_material, container, 
false);

    int[] pizzaImages = new int[Pizza.pizzas.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < pizzaImages.length; i++){
        pizzaImages[i] = Pizza.pizzas[i].getImageResourceId();
    }

List<Pizza> namesItem = db.getItem();

LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity,
        LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

pizzaRecycler.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
pizzaRecycler.setAdapter(new CaptionedImagesAdapter(namesItem));

    return pizzaRecycler;
```

Это метод с использованием другой библиотеки считывания данных с БД, но в целом механизм такой, немного упорядочите и расставите как надо.

Comment: И далее в методе onCreate: в каком файле?  RecyclerView pizzaRecycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(this);  Выдает ошибку

Comment: И еще происходит конфликт в PizzaDatabaseHelper список это List<Pizza> а в CaptionedImagesAdapter это int[] imageIds. Как это все исправить?

Comment: Отредактировал, попробуйте сейчас

Comment: LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);  ругается на this. а еще не находит pizzas в int[] pizzaImages = new int[Pizza.pizzas.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < pizzaImages.length; i++){
            pizzaImages[i] = Pizza.pizzas[i].getImageResourceId();
        }     'List<Pizza> namesItem = db.getItem();'а здесь не реализована db

Comment: @Марк Стариков Замените this на getActvity. Я оставил ваш метод, как вы в нем бд реализовали я не знаю.

Comment: @МаркСтариков https://github.com/ga-adi-macaron/databases-with-recyclerview-lab/tree/master/solution-code/ShoppingListVer2/app/src/main скачайте эти исходники, и изучите их.

Comment: @МаркСтариков есть проще https://github.com/isaacurbina/RecyclerView/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/mobileappsco/training/day6hw